# Custom listview with shodows to the listview row in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I know how to make a custom listview with Layout inflator and use of the xml layout for row of listview. But I want to know how different styles we can apply on the listview row like I shown one below.

[image: Listview with shadows in rows]

Comment: That's simply setting background for custom view(item). Here in this picture, 2 pics are used, one for first item and another for rest items.

Comment: This is background image which is having 3D look, use this image as a background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is `listview_item_shadow.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        </shape>
    </item>
     <item 
         android:right="1dp" 
         android:bottom="2dp">        
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
              <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        </shape>
     </item>         
</layer-list>
```

Now you should use it in selector for ItemView! - `listview_item_backgroundstate.xml` You need to set `listview_item_backgroundstate.xml` as background to your ListView item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/listview_item_shadow"></item>
</selector>
```

And at last you have to set custom_selector.xml as in ListView. `android:listSelector="@drawable/custom_selector.xml"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item  
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@android:drawable/color/white" />  
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_background_blue" />  
</selector>
```

Or use that kind of image as background for every list item..